# No such property: name for class: java.lang.String Open File

Tags: java, android, wikitude-sdk

I pulled the following code from Wikitude examples but still getting build error. 
**No such property: name for class: java.lang.String Open File**
What am I missing?

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all  { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            def fileName = "wikitude-sdk-samples-" + variant.buildType.name + ".apk"
            output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure but `def` is not String and you are acting on it as String `outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')`

Comment: Are you trying to change name of file here ?

Comment: idk! I'm just an intern trying to run this code.

Comment: any suggestion will do...

Comment: Its a standard example from wikitude. I'm just trying to make it run.

Answer (score -1):

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all  { output ->
        if (outputFileName != null && outputFileName.endsWith('.apk')) {
            def fileName = "wikitude-sdk-samples-" + variant.buildType.name + ".apk"
            output.outputFileName = new File(outputFileName, fileName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: explain this answer

Comment: Explain this answer!